# VBA MACRO to color ONE cell right to the Selected cells

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a macro that makes a formatting rule of multiple cell areas and must paint the cell yellow if it contains "S" and it works. But I would also like the cell to the right of the cell that contains "S" painted yellow, but only one cell to the right - not the whole row, is that possible? I imagine it's going to take place inside the "WITH statement, but I can not really move on

```
Sub Makro2()
    Range("D6:E30,G6:H30,J6:K30,M6:N30,P6:Q30").Select
    Range("P6").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""S"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want setting a formatting rule to the "P6" cell, or to the discontinue range? Since, the discontinue range has areas of two columns, the column E:E of the first area is already conditional formatted. I mean, being "on cell to the right of D:D... The idea is that a format condition acts only to the cell it belongs. But the same code can be adapted to simultaneously format the next cell to the right. If interested, I can show you how you can accomplish it for a cell. Theoretically, it ca be done for only the first right column of each discontinuous range, but a little more complicated.

Comment: In order to know if is the case, if I will find some time, to solve the much more complicated discontinuous range, I would like to know how you need the formatting to behave. For instance if an "S" exists in "D10", but **no "S" in "E10" having its own formatted**, do you like that "E10" to be also highlighted  (yellow interior)?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that explained properly, P6 is just the last active cell when I record the macro and mark areas up. I just inserted a picture in the question for better understanding. As I write, my conditional formatting works for my areas, but I just want the cell to the right of the formatted cells painted as well

Comment: I understood that you say, but I did not understand **what you mean**... I asked a question in my previous comment, **regarding the "E10" cel behavior if it does not have an "S" like value, but "D10" has**.  Should its interior be yellow, or not? Should I ask it again? Isn't it clear in terms of what I meant?

Comment: Then, your picture does not show any "S" in columns E, H, K ... Is your discontinue range build mistakenly? Did you missed showing us such a situation? Your request involves that the column I mentioned above to also be conditioned to make yellow interior in case of an "S"...

Comment: I am afraid that your question, especially after showing the range `Range("D6:E30,G6:H30,J6:K30,M6:N30,P6:Q30")` and telling about the next right cell to be yellow, is completely confusing. Looking to the picture appearing later, after I worked based on your initial question, the range should only contain a single column per area...

Comment: Still alive? Please, try testing the last code I posted (second edit) and send some feedback. There is another answer, too. Please, also test it and say something...

Comment: Sorry for my long response times, I live in a world with small children ;-), First I just want to say that your last response works perfectly :-).

Comment: I do not know if it makes sense to answer the questions now, but I do anyway. The F column should only be formatted based on what the D column shows, The question with "S" I do not quite understand "S" is not a column, but the letter I check on (maybe I misunderstand the question, English is not my mother tongue) You have completely right in RANGE ("D6: D30, ...) It was just because in a previous attempt I was able to get it to paint in F if I had it in RANGE. But again 1000 thanks for the help

Comment: OK. Now, please check the other answer, too and choose the one you like better. We here, when somebody spends some time and answer our question, tick his code left check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works and it is appreciate like being the best. Our main goal here is to help people asking questions, but also giving a tool to the future searches to easier find what they need...

Comment: I understood that "S" was only a string to be placed in a cel, but seeing your range you tried (in code) to conditional formate, it looked obvious that this "S" should be placed in column E, D, J, H etc. That's why I asked abut the "S" in columns  E, H, K ... For such a question, the second area range should have two conditions and this is what I did in the code after my first edit.

Comment: To finalize, I would appreciate it if you could share what was the desired result. I know that some cell(s) had to contain an `s` and some cell(s) had to be painted. You could clarify (at least for me) by answering the following 3 questions: If `D6` is equal to `s` what should be painted? If `E6` is equal to `s` what should be painted? And if `F6` is equal to `s` what should then be painted? A possible answer could e.g. be `1. D6, F6; 2. E6; 3. nothing`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the s, it was bad luck that I accidentally got the S column pressed in my macro. If D contains an "S" then D and E must be painted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried explaining in a comment the involvements of trying to conditional format of a discontinuous range. For the cell **really processed by your shown code**, you can accomplish what you need using the next code. The basis of conditional formatting behavior is that it **formats only the cell where the conditional format belongs**:

```
Sub Makro2Bis()
    Dim rng As Range, offrng As Range
    Set rng = Range("P6"): Set offrng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""S"""
        .FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    With offrng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Address(0, 0) & "= ""S"""
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Edited**:

Please, test the (more complicated) version creating the conditional formatting for the discontinue range, in a way you asked for: The right neighbour cell will have the interior yellow, too:

```
Sub Makro3Bis()
 Dim rng As Range, arr, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
 
 Set rng = Range("D6:E30,G6:H30,J6:K30,M6:N30,P6:Q30")
 arr = buildThreeRngs(rng)
 Set rng1 = arr(0) 'the first column of the discontinuous range areas
 Set rng2 = arr(1) 'the second column of the discontinuous range areas
 Set rng3 = arr(2) 'the next column after the discontinuous range areas
 
 With rng1
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""S"""
    .FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
 End With
 With rng2 'it will have two conditions. The second one relative to its left neighbour cell.
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""S"""
    .FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng1.cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= ""S"""
    .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = rng1.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
    .FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = False
 End With
 With rng3
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng2.cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= ""S"""
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
 End With
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Second Edit**:

Looking only to your picture and not basing on the code you posted, probably, the my first code (for one cell) adapted in the next way should be what you need:

```
Sub Makro2BisBis()
    Dim rng As Range, offrng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D6:D30,G6:G30,J6:J30,M6:M30,P6:P30")
    Set offrng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    Debug.Print offrng.Address: Stop
    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""S"""
        .FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    With offrng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= ""S"""
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```

It will make yellow the cells in the range you have in your code, but using only each area first column...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

### Conditional Formatting in VBA

- For the second part in `Excel`, you would use the following `Conditional Formatting` formula:

  ```
  =D6="s"
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Makro2()
    
    Const ColOffset As Long = 1
    Const Criteria As String = "s"
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("D6:D30,G6:G30,J6:J30,M6:M30,P6:P30")
    
    ' xlCellValue
    With rg
        .ClearFormats
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:="=""" & Criteria & """"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
    
    ' xlExpression
    With rg.Offset(, ColOffset)
        .ClearFormats
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=" & .Cells(1).Offset(, -ColOffset).Address(0, 0) _
                & "=""" & Criteria & """"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```